# Fill textbox with corresponding data of dropdown RestAPI Sharepoint Online

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, sharepoint-online, rest

The working code below loads option values of dropdown id REG returned from the RestAPI call.

I would like to take the value of Title and fill its corresponding family value (returned in the same RestAPI call) into the textbox id Family with on change javascript event. Please advice.

```
<script>
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getAR);
var jresult;
function getAR() {
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List_Name')/items?$Select=Title,Family",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {"accept": "application / json;odata = verbose",},
        success: function(data) {
            jresult = data.d.jresult;
            var options = "";
            for(var i = 0; i < jresult.length; i++){
                options = options + "<option value='" + jresult[i].Title + "'>" + jresult[i].Title + "</option>";
            }
            $("#REG").append(options);
        },
        error: function(error) {alert(JSON.stringify(error));}
    });
}
function fillFamily() {
  var x = document.getElementById("REG").value;
  $( "Family" ).val( x.Family );
}
</script>

<select id="REG" name="REG" class="custom-select" required="required" onchange="fillFamily()"></select>
<input type="text" id="Family" name="Family">
```

Comment: Store `results` in a global variable for later access. Use a `change` event handler for your `<select>` and inside, read from the array based on `this.value` (which is the Title).

Comment: Hi Chris, I've updated the code i have right now. Could you pls have a look and advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code, you could have a try.  Corrected the error in your code.

```
 <script>
        $(function(){
            getAR() 
        })
        var jresult;
        function getAR() {
            $.ajax({
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('2/23')/items?$Select=Title",
                type: "GET",
                headers: {"accept": "application / json;odata = verbose",},
                success: function(data) {
                    jresult = data.d.results;
                    var options = "";
                    for(var i = 0; i < jresult.length; i++){
                        options = options + "<option value='" + jresult[i].Title + "'>" + jresult[i].Title + "</option>";
                    }
                    $("#REG").append(options);
                },
                error: function(error) {alert(JSON.stringify(error));}
            });
        }
        function fillFamily() {
           
          var x = document.getElementById("REG").value;
          $( "#Family" ).val( x );
        }
        </script>
        
        <select id="REG" name="REG" class="custom-select" required="required" onchange="fillFamily()"></select>
        <input type="text" id="Family" name="Family">
```

[image]

**Updated:**

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        getAR() 
    })
    var jresult;
    function getAR() {
        $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('2/23')/items?$Select=Title,Family",
            type: "GET",
            headers: {"accept": "application / json;odata = verbose",},
            success: function(data) {
                jresult = data.d.results;
                var options = "";
                for(var i = 0; i < jresult.length; i++){
                    options = options + "<option value='" + jresult[i].Title + "'Family="+jresult[i].Family+">" + jresult[i].Title + "</option>";
                }
                $("#REG").append(options);
            },
            error: function(error) {alert(JSON.stringify(error));}
        });
    }
    function fillFamily() {
        var val=$("#REG").find("option:selected").attr("Family");
      $( "#Family" ).val( val );
    }
    </script>
    
    <select id="REG" name="REG" class="custom-select" required="required" onchange="fillFamily()"></select>
    <input type="text" id="Family" name="Family">
```

Comment: Hi Amos, your code works to fill the value from Title on the test box. However, i wish to fill the value of Family corresponding to the selected title in the Textbox (not title). Pls refer my API call select values. Appreciate the assistance.

Comment: Your code does not use the value of Family, you need to add it. Check my update.